# When to use index and seeds arguments of train() in caret package in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, machine-learning, data-mining, r-caret

Primary Question:

After reading the documentation and google searching, I am still stumped as to what the situations are where it is advisable to pre-define resampling indices such as:

```
resamples <- createResample(classVector_training, times = 500, list=TRUE)
```

or predefine seeds such as:

```
seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = 501) #length is = (n_repeats*nresampling)+1
for(i in 1:501) seeds[[i]]<- sample.int(n=1000, 1)
```

My plan is to train a bunch of different reproducible models using parallel processing via the doParallel package.  Is predefining resamples unnecessary due to the seeds already being set? Do I need to predefine seeds in the way above instead of setting seeds=NULL in the trainControl object because I intend to use parallel processing? Is there any reason to pre-define both index and seeds as I've seen at least once via searching google? And what is a reason to ever use indexOut?

Side Question:

So far, I've managed to run train fine for RF:

```
rfControl <- trainControl(method="oob", number = 500, p = 0.7, returnData=TRUE,   returnResamp = "all", savePredictions=TRUE, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, allowParallel=TRUE)
mtryGrid <- expand.grid(mtry = 9480^0.5) #set mtry parameter to the square root of the number of variables
rfTrain <- train(x = training, y = classVector_training, method = "rf", trControl = rfControl, tuneGrid = mtryGrid)
```

But when I try to run train() with method = "baruta" as such:

```
borutaControl <- trainControl(method="bootstrap", number = 500, p = 0.7, returnData=TRUE, returnResamp = "all", savePredictions=TRUE, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, allowParallel=TRUE)
borutaTrain <- train(x = training, y = classVector_training, method = "Boruta", trControl = borutaControl, tuneGrid = mtryGrid)
```

I end up getting the following error:

```
Error in names(trControl$indexOut) <- prettySeq(trControl$indexOut) : 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: The SO overlords would rather that we used the tag `R-caret`

Comment: Maybe use `floor(9480^0.5)` instead to get an integer.

Answer (score 9):

There are a few different times random numbers are used here, so I'll try to be specific about which seeds.

> Is predefining resamples unnecessary due to the seeds already being set?

If you do not provide your own resampling indices, the first things that `train`, `rfe`, `sbf`, `gafs`, and `safs` do is to create them. So, **setting the overall seed** prior to calling these controls the randomness of creating resamples. So, you can call these functions repeatedly and use the same samples of you set the main seed beforehand:

```
set.seed(2346)
mod1 <- train(y ~ x, data = dat, method = "a", ...)

set.seed(2346)
mod2 <- train(y ~ x, data = dat, method = "b", ...)

set.seed(2346)
mod3 <- rfe(x, y, ...)
```

You can use `createResamples` or `createFolds` if you like and give those to `trainControl`'s `index` argument too.

One other note about this: if `indexOut` is missing, the holdouts are defined as whatever samples were not used to train the model. There are cases when this is bad (see the exception below) and that is why `indexOut` exists.

> Do I need to predefine seeds in the way above instead of setting seeds=NULL in the trainControl object because I intend to use parallel processing?

That was the main intent. When the worker processes startup, there was no way to control the randomness inside the model fit prior to our addition of the `seeds` argument. You don't *have to* use it, but it will lead to reproducible models.

Note that, like resamples, `train` will create seeds for you if you do not supply them. They are found in the `control$seeds` element in the `train` object.

Note that `trainControl(seeds)` has nothing to do with creating the resamples.

> Is there any reason to pre-define both index and seeds as I've seen at least once via searching google?

If you want to pre-define the resamples and control any potential randomness in the worker processes that build the models, then yes.

> And what is a reason to ever use indexOut?

There are always specialized situations. The reason it is there is for [time series data](http://topepo.github.io/caret/splitting.html#time) where you might have data splits that do not involve all the samples passed to `train` (this is the exception mentioned above).  See the white space in [this graphic](http://topepo.github.io/caret/figure/Split_time.png).

**tl/dr**

- `trainControl(seeds)` **only** controls the randomness of the model fits
- setting the seed prior to calling `train` is one way to control the randomness of data splitting

Max

Comment: Minor item, but I think you were trying to type `set.seed` not `set.sedd`. Unless there is a call there that I haven't heard of before...